# Reorder GridLayout SWT

Tags: java, swt

I Have a GridLayout filled with Composites in a random order. Now I'm sorting the Composites that are filling the GridLayout in a List/Collection and want to order them like the sort result from my List/Collection. I tried to do it by allocating them again to their parent so they are in the right order, but for some reason nothing happened. Then I tried to cache them in a Composite you don't see and then bring them back to the parent with the same method as in the first attempt. No change at all. Anyone has a pointer? I'm ordering by date, just in case /so want to know.

Thats how my grid looks like, now I want to order them like in my arrayList();

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The methods you are looking for are `Control#moveAbove(Control control)` and `Control#moveBelow(Control control)` to reorder the items:

```
private static List<Label>  labels  = new ArrayList<Label>();
private static List<Color>  colors  = new ArrayList<Color>();

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("Stackoverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    colors.add(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));
    colors.add(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_CYAN));
    colors.add(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN));
    colors.add(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_YELLOW));
    colors.add(display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        label.setText("Button " + i);
        label.setBackground(colors.get(i));

        labels.add(label);
    }

    Button sortButton = new Button(shell, SWT.TOGGLE);
    sortButton.setText("Sort");

    sortButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event e)
        {
            Button source = (Button) e.widget;

            final boolean asc = source.getSelection();

            Label oldFirst = labels.get(0);

            Collections.sort(labels, new Comparator<Label>()
            {
                @Override
                public int compare(Label o1, Label o2)
                {
                    int result = o1.getText().compareTo(o2.getText());

                    if (asc)
                        result = -result;

                    return result;
                }
            });

            Label label = labels.get(0);
            label.moveAbove(oldFirst);

            for (int i = 1; i < labels.size(); i++)
            {
                labels.get(i).moveBelow(labels.get(i - 1));
            }
            shell.layout();
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

After starting:

[image]

After pressing the button:

[image]

Comment: @Johnny000 Cheers mate. Appreciate it.

Comment: isn't the moveAbove() and moveBelow() only for the z-axis? i am having the same problem and the moveAbove/moveBelow won't change the order at all

Comment: @Stoppal That depends. Some `Layout`s interpret it as the z-order, whereas `RowLayout` uses it for the x- or y-order (horizontal or vertical ordering) depending on its own orientation.

Comment: Sorry to have waited so long for the response @Baz. Of course you were right, my mistake was that i tried to move my own widget, that defines it's own control and said control had to be moved, not the widget itself, that's why it didn't work for me. So maybe this will help someone having the same problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. You have to call `child.moveAbove(otherChild)` or `.moveBelow()` When you are done with the reordering just call on the parent Composite `parent.layout()`